# Is there any way to tweak consumer configurations in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm modifying memsql Kafka Connector code and it seems Kafka connect does not use Kafka consumer subscribe API so I'm wondering if there is any way to change configurations of consumer such as group id, partition assignment strategy,...?

Comment: Refer docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running scroll down to where it mentions overrides

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to override consumer's configuration at the worker level:

```
consumer.auto.offset.reset=latest
```

or at the connector level:

```
"consumer.override.auto.offset.reset": "latest"
```